# Cannot export table in SQL format in phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I want to export my SQL table from phpMyAdmin, but in my server I cannot choose SQL format because it does not exist.

I also can't export the total SQL file. After I click Go, my browser shows an error.

How I can fix this?

[image: screenshot of problem]

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53801915/10676716)

Answer (score 21):

They do have a fix in place now:

**Resources:** [Issue 14775](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14775) | [Fix for 14775](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/95114841420af6277b0406ec7f0d32c4ff3fcf27)

Follow these steps:

1. Connect to the server via SSH. (I'd recommend saving original file first just in case)
2. Edit file `/usr/local/psa/admin/htdocs/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin/libraries/classes/Display/Export.php`.

**!Note:** for Windows, it will be `%plesk_dir%admin\htdocs\domains\databases\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Display\Export.php`.

3. Find line `/* Scan for plugins */` (*around line 662*)
4. Add the following above the line:

---

```
// Export a single table

if (isset($_GET['single_table'])) {

    $GLOBALS['single_table'] = $_GET['single_table'];

}
```

5. Save the file.

More references [here](https://www.vswsystems.com/phpmyadmin-mysql-table-export-sql-format-missing/).

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm ... maybe the should use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET/$_POST

Comment: Awesome. For XAMPP on Mac OS this is in Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Display/Export.php.

Just add the code and refresh browser.

Comment: Thx a lot! Same Settings for Wamp64 - wamp64\apps\phpmyadminX.X.X\libraries\classes\Display\Export.php

Answer (score 14):

Until issue is resolved you could try another way: Open the table you would like to export then go all the way down and see Query results operations. In there you could export query result and here is an option with SQL. In my case this works ok.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If it is phpMyAdmin 4.8.4, then you probably have encountered this issue: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14775

It should be fixed in the next couple of days, with the next update - meanwhile, you could try to use an older version of phpMyAdmin for export or mysqldump (or some other means to export the DB\table).

Comment: Thanks , yes it is phpmyadmin 4.8.4 
How i can downgrade this version?

Comment: Depends on how it is installed - using package manager (e.g. with "apt-get" on Debian\Ubuntu, etc) or manually.

If it's installed manually, you can get older versions from https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/releases or https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/ - and then use process similar to upgrading (replace the current phpmyadmin with the files from old version and move the config).

Otherwise - it depends on your distro.

But I would recommend to wait until the bug is fixed and to use mysqldump for export for now, instead of downgrading - if you have shell access to the server.

Answer (score 2):

```
1. Go to C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin(YOUR_PHP_VERSION)\libraries\classes\Display
2. open Export.php
3. look for line /* Scan for plugins */ (near 662)
4. check if following lines are set or not

if (isset($_POST['single_table'])) {
$GLOBALS['single_table'] = $_POST['single_table'];
}
if (isset($_GET['single_table'])) {
$GLOBALS['single_table'] = $_GET['single_table'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug.
You can simply, on the first tab, select all the data and click on the export button at the bottom right.
The sql option will be defaulted.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wQkz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to export is using CLI:

```
mysqldump -u your_user -p your_database table1 table2 ... > database_tables.sql
```

Comment: Thanks for this workaround.  I'm guessing most people who use phpmyadmin have an aversion to the CLI or don't have access to it.

Comment: Yes, you're right, so, I think that is a temporary solution meanwhile came the update.

Answer (score 0):

In xampp file `Export.php`:

```
/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Display
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is present in the script, just Change POST to REQUEST method

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['single_table'])) {
$GLOBALS['single_table'] = $_REQUEST['single_table'];
}
```