# Why has the latest phpmyadmin dropped sql as export format?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, export

I am using phpmyadmin 4.8.4 and have tried to export one of my tables as backup.  I noticed that sql has been dropped as an export file type.

Why has this happened?  I now have to export as CSV and then if I want to import, I need to drop the table first.  Then, after I import the CSV, I need to rename the table and make sure it is uses the same collation as the original.  This is whole lot more work then when I could use sql as it imported everything and without needing all the extra work.

Please can someone put sql back!!!

Thanks,

Mark King MCP

Answer (score 1):

They do have a fix out now...

[Fix for 14775](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/95114841420af6277b0406ec7f0d32c4ff3fcf27)

Essentially:

1. Connect to the server via SSH.
2. Open file /usr/local/psa/admin/htdocs/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin/libraries/classes/Display/Export.php with a text editor.
   Note: for Windows, it will be %plesk_dir%admin\htdocs\domains\databases\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Display\Export.php.
3. Find line "/* Scan for plugins */"
4. Add the following above the line:

   // Export a single table

   ```
       if (isset($_GET['single_table'])) {

           $GLOBALS['single_table'] = $_GET['single_table'];

       }
   ```
5. Save the file.

[More Reference.](https://www.vswsystems.com/phpmyadmin-mysql-table-export-sql-format-missing/)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the phpmyadmin install you can do a select on the table  then at base of page in "Query results operations" click the little export icon.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug in the phpmyadmin 4.8.4. A [github issue](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14775) has been opened 5 days ago, and development team informed yesterday that a fix should be provided within a few days in version 4.8.4.1