# I can not export in phpmyadmin if I do a custom query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a custom query like this one:

```
SELECT
    reports.id_report_type as capitulation_type_id,
    (
        CASE accountabilities.`id_report` WHEN 1 THEN 39 ELSE 33 END
    ) as dte_type_id,
    `id_branch_office` as branch_office_id,
    `id_accountability_type` as expense_type_id,
    accountabilities.document_number,
    users.rut as rut,
    description,
    amount,
    `document_date`,
    (
        CASE accountabilities.`id_report` WHEN 1 THEN 39 ELSE 33 END
    ) as dte_type_id,
    (
        CASE accountabilities.`status` WHEN 0 THEN 11 WHEN 1 THEN 7 WHEN 4 THEN 17 END
    ) as status_id,
    `file` as support
FROM
    `accountabilities`
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.id_user = accountabilities.id_user
    LEFT JOIN reports ON reports.id_report = reports.id_report
WHERE
    accountabilities.date >= '2021-01-01'
    AND (
        accountabilities.`status` = 0
        OR accountabilities.`status` = 1
        OR accountabilities.status = 4
    )
```

But when I do that it does not allow me to export using SQL, it displays codegen and I do not want that..

1. I do the custom query.
   [step 1][image: 1]
2. I execute the custom query.
   [step 2][image: 2]
3. I push export.
   [step 2][image: 2]
4. SQL does not appear but codegen does.
   [step 3][image: 3]

what could the problem be?

Comment: Is there any other options in the format drop down??

Comment: @nacho yes CVS, CVS for expel, codegen, php array, but it does not appear sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot export table in SQL format in phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53798207/cannot-export-table-in-sql-format-in-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
     , CASE a.id_report WHEN 1 THEN 39 ELSE 33 END dte_type_id
     , ...
     , CASE a.id_report WHEN 1 THEN 39 ELSE 33 END dte_type_id
...
```

Maybe bin it and start over.